# Rails - conditionally set a search parameter on index view based on geolocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Restaurants model and for the index path, I'd like to pass in a default search parameter if the user navigates to /restaurants.

My user interface is based around a search bar, but if the user goes to the index view of the Restaurant model directly, I do not want it to be empty since nothing has been searched.

I am using Sunspot for the search and my controller code looks like this:

```
empty_search = params[:search] ? false : true

if empty_search
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all
else
    @search = Sunspot.search(Restaurant) do
    fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @restaurants = @search.results
end
```

However, I do not want to ultimately return all restaurants if no search parameter was passed in.

How would I do something like passing in the user's city (based on Geocoder geolocation), since one of the search attributes is the restuarant's city?

Answer (score 0):

```
request.location.city
```

This should contain user city.